# How to create connection with the database in another computer using a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a network based application client will be using the data from the database which is in server computer so I want to create a `SqlConnection` with the database on the server computer so could you please help me with this. If any confusion with the question please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Connection string

```
string _conStr =  @"Data Source=198.162.10\YourServername;Initial
Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Connect Timeout=50;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword";
```